# What is the iPad2 User-Agent string?

Tags: ipad, user-agent, ipad-2

Does anyone know the user-agent string of the just released iPad2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is my most recent user agent record from my ipad 2:

```
Mozilla/5.0(iPad; U; CPU OS 4_3 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8F191 Safari/6533.18.5
```

Comment: It's similar to the user agent from the iPad. There's no way to differenciate between iPad 1 and 2. (http://www.webtrends.com/Support/KnowledgeBase/SolutionDetail.aspx?Id=50140000000acbiAAA)

Comment: I find that there IS a difference. Viewing in Safari on Windows works whereas the IPad 2 in the office doesn't.  I suspect it's the JavaScript library but the point is that it doesn't render the player on iPad 2.

Answer (score 1):

iPad 2 with iOS 5.1

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B176 Safari/7534.48.3
```